# Cannot interact with docker container: stop, rm, inspect... command line just stucked

Tags: docker

I'm having problems with a couple of containers in my docker swarm. I tried to stop them but nothing happens. Every time I try to interact withn them (inspect, console, kill, rm even with -f) nothing happens and command line got stuck until I press Ctrl+C. The hilarious part is that docker ls shows them as "healthy".

Restart docker service seems the usual solution with these kind of behavior but as far as this is a production environment with lots of other services running I cannot do that. Rest of containers, services, stacks... work as expected.

Is there any possibility or alternative way to remove/kill that containers?

```
xxxxx1 amancevice/superset:0.27.0  "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              prd_yyyy_superset_dashboard.
xxxxx2 xxxxxxx/mysql-xxxxxx:5911   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months             3306/tcp                                              prd_yyyy_api_mysql.1.
xxxxx3 amancevice/superset:0.27.0  "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              prd_yyyy_superset_dashboard.1
```

Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6

Update:
I've just found there are more "healthy" containers in my docker swarm with the same behavior. I cannot interact in any way to them, cannot kill, restart, inspect, remove or doing nothing. They are just there

```
d7c13e9d8115        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              
7137cf54fe56        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              prd_avis_superset_dashboard.1.s5x7cktaiwhv6juv6f7nmpfv6
43fe34109330        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              
ccf45223b412        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              
253f411cd403        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              prd_philips_superset_dashboard.1.qfyufa6flfzz0vgqebkzu1432
ff14a3967b7b        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              
987f22985036        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              
27f42f0733aa        kibana:5.6.11                                      "/docker-entrypoint.…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   5601/tcp                                              
b77a12659bcc        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp                                              
628842bc6e2a        amancevice/superset:0.27.0                         "gunicorn superset:a…"   2 months ago        Up 2 months (healthy)   8088/tcp
```

UPDATE 2: FIX
I don't know if it is the better way but finally I've found that killing the process seems teh simpler way to be able to restar service.

Just get the process id with:

```
# ps -ef | grep 43fe34109330
root      8789 32768  0  2018 ?        00:00:40 docker-containerd-shim -namespace moby -workdir /var/lib/docker/containerd/daemon/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/43fe3410933077a0f6c98cbbc04e4db4d2eae1b37f073059b4f76a4f8478dd15 -address /var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock -containerd-binary /usr/bin/docker-containerd -runtime-root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc
```

and kill it with

```
#kill 8789
```

The container finally ends and I'm able to create it again.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ says: "If the daemon is completely non-responsive, you can also force a full stack trace of all threads to be added to the daemon log by sending the SIGUSR signal to the Docker daemon."

Answer (score -1):

Try maybe killing the process *gunicorn* in you containers with a *docker exec*, even if I doubt it will work, if containers are frozen.

Comment: thanks for your help but was unable to reach that process, however you answer give me the clue for looking the container process id and kill it